# SQL - Expecting ID Error when attempting to Create Table with Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a table but it is giving me an error saying it is Expecting ID. Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

My query is as follows:

```
Create Table ForecastSnapshot as

(
SELECT x.* 

FROM
(
(
SELECT [Opportunity ID] 
      ,[Last Modified Date]
      ,[Close Date] 
      ,[Stage] 
      ,[ARR] 
      ,[TCM] 
      ,[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] 
      ,'2015-07-06' as [Snapshot Date] 


  FROM table1


  ) x

RIGHT JOIN (

SELECT  max([SYSTEMMODSTAMP]) as [SYSTEMMODSTAMP], [Opportunity ID]
FROM table1
WHERE [SYSTEMMODSTAMP] < '2015-07-06'                                                         
GROUP BY [Opportunity ID]

) as y 

ON x.[Opportunity ID] = y.[Opportunity ID] AND x.[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] = y.[SYSTEMMODSTAMP]
```

Comment: The first "(" under the FROM is not match and is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is SELECT...INTO statement:

```
SELECT x.* INTO ForecastSnapshot 
FROM
(
SELECT [Opportunity ID] 
  ,[Last Modified Date]
  ,[Close Date] 
  ,[Stage] 
  ,[ARR] 
  ,[TCM] 
  ,[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] 
  ,'2015-07-06' as [Snapshot Date] 
  FROM table1
  ) x

RIGHT JOIN (

SELECT  max([SYSTEMMODSTAMP]) as [SYSTEMMODSTAMP], [Opportunity ID]
FROM table1
WHERE [SYSTEMMODSTAMP] < '2015-07-06'                                                         
GROUP BY [Opportunity ID]

) as y 

ON x.[Opportunity ID] = y.[Opportunity ID] AND x.[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] = y.[SYSTEMMODSTAMP]
```